# Flux error when migrating from inline <flux:form options={...}> to <flux:form.option.* />

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

## The Problem

I’m getting the following error and I don’t know why or how to fix it

```
Call to undefined method FluidTYPO3\Flux\Form\Container\Sheet::setOption()
```

I am trying to get things working after disabling `fluidpages` and upgrading `flux` 9.4. I think I have done the database updates correctly. I’m using: `typo3` 8.7, `flux` 9.4, no `fluidcontent`, no `fluidpages`, `vhs`.

*Note: This is also cross posted in the TYPO3's `Flux` Slack channel where it's easier to have longer live conversations if needed.*

## My Code

Here’s what I had before in `fluidbootstraptheme/Resources/Private/Templates/Content/Carousel.html`

```
    <f:section name="Configuration">
        <flux:form id="carousel" options="{group: 'Bootstrap', sorting: 200, icon: 'EXT:fluidbootstraptheme/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/Carousel.png'}">
```

Here’s what I have now in `fluidbootstraptheme/Resources/Private/Templates/Content/Carousel.html`

```
    <f:section name="Configuration">
        <flux:form id="carousel">
            <flux:form.option.group value="Bootstrap" />
            <flux:form.option.sorting value="200" />
            <flux:form.option.icon value="EXT:fluidbootstraptheme/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/Carousel.png" />
```

## Additional References

Here's some things that might help and I might have misunderstood, hence my site isn't working yet

- https://www.aemka.de/en/news/update-from-extflux-8-to-9.html
- https://www.aemka.de/en/news/fluid-pages-page-layouts-without-fluidpages.html
- https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/1542

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Claus Due he pointed out that in one of my files I had accidentally placed `flux:form.option` inside of `flux:form.sheet` instead of directly inside `flux:form`. He also kindly [added code to check for this specific error in Flux](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/commit/4259e58497353e37ad7f9d812a22cc530c81366b) in the future.

## The wrong way

```
<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:form id="progressBar">
        <flux:form.sheet name="progressBar">
            <flux:form.option.group value="Bootstrap" />
            <flux:form.option.sorting value="650" />
            <flux:form.option.icon value="EXT:yourextension/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/ProgressBar.png" />
            <flux:field.checkbox name="settings.progressBarAnimated" default="0" />
            <flux:field.checkbox name="settings.progressBarStriped" default="0" />
            <flux:field.select name="settings.progressBarColor"
```

## The right way

```
<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:form id="progressBar">
        <flux:form.option.group value="Bootstrap" />
        <flux:form.option.sorting value="650" />
        <flux:form.option.icon value="EXT:yourextension/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/ProgressBar.png" />
        <flux:form.sheet name="progressBar">
            <flux:field.checkbox name="settings.progressBarAnimated" default="0" />
            <flux:field.checkbox name="settings.progressBarStriped" default="0" />
            <flux:field.select name="settings.progressBarColor"
```

## Way to improve the above code

@Claus Due also pointed out that there's usually no need to use `flux:form.option.icon` if you use special conventions.

> copy whichever icon files you associate with content/page templates, to Resources/Public/Icons/Content or Resources/Public/Icons/Page and name them like the page/content template is named. Then remove the “icon” option from forms

So for this snippet from the file `typo3conf/ext/yourextension/Resources/Private/Templates/Content/ProgressBar.html` I leave out the icon line...

```
<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:form id="progressBar">
        <flux:form.option.group value="Bootstrap" />
        <flux:form.option.sorting value="650" />
        <flux:form.sheet name="progressBar">
            <flux:field.checkbox name="settings.progressBarAnimated" default="0" />
            <flux:field.checkbox name="settings.progressBarStriped" default="0" />
            <flux:field.select name="settings.progressBarColor"
```

...and just make sure to add an icon specifically located and named `typo3conf/ext/yourextension/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/ProgressBar.png`

[image: ProgressBar.png]

*Note: I abstracted `fluidbootstraptheme` to `yourextension` in the above code make it a little more obvious what gets replaced in your specific case.*